# Skype notifications repeat themselves endlessly

Tags: skype, notifications

For some notifications Skype gives me, even after I close them and mark them as read, they come back again the next day.

Even after several weeks, notifications of the same event keep on appearing again and again.

How can I stop the notifications constantly repeating?

I don't know if it's related, but I run Skype on two computers simultaneously: one Ubuntu, one Windows 7.

Comment: I have similar issue: one of contacts show very old message as new every time I launch Skype on other computer.